# Clear part of the state

Tags: angular, state-management, ngxs

I'm a bit in doubt about a solution I came up with for clearing part of the state.

I have a page called "Books" where I get an array of books. Each book object contains very minimal information necessary for that page. When the user clicks on a book, they are redirected to a single book page where I'd fetch the full book information.

My state looks like this:

```
@State<any>({
  name: 'books',
  defaults: {
    books: [],
    selectedBook: null
  }
})
```

When the user navigates away from the single book page, I'd like to clear the `selectedBook` because it feels weird (to me at least) to be in other parts of the app and still have a `selectedBook` laying around.

I was wondering how to achieve that and the best solution I could come up with was to dispatch a `ClearSelectedBook` action from a `CanDeactivate` guard on the `books/:id` route.

Here's a [demo on StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngxs-simple-mtbded).

Is this the right approach and if not what other alternatives are there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if there is a *right* way but an alternative is to use the NGXS [Router Plugin](https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/plugins/router)

The state could handle the `RouterNavigation` action, and look at the action payload - if it has navigated away from the single book page, then clear the `selectedBook` value in the state.

Having said that - your approach to use an explict action has it's advantages (imho) - I might rename it though, perhaps to `UserLeftBookPage` .. then have the state respond to that.  Rather than the action name indicating the response.  Writing tests is also a bit more straightforward with an explict action rather than tapping into the router.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Didn't know about the Router Plugin before (even though it seems obvious now and it's pretty easy to find in the docs, I'd say) so it's nice to have it as an option. I'll give it a try and see how it can help me in this or any other future case.

Comment: No problem - in our app we have a used the router plugin, and some explicit actions to model scenarios like this.  E.g. we have a map component, and we want to modifiy state when the user navigates away from the map to any other screen, so we list for that route change via an the action stream.